# Including Package Data Python from Top-level when Package is in Subdirectory

Tags: python, setuptools, python-packaging

I'm trying to package a series of configuration files along with some source code. I have a directory structure like this (which I cannot change, due to the nature of the team)

```
.
├── configs
│   ├── machines
│   ├── scope
├── esm_tools
│   ├── __init__.py
├── README.rst
├── setup.cfg
├── setup.py

61 directories, 45 files (Truncated)
```

From what I understand here (https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-package-data), I can add some parts to the setup call:

```py
setup(
    # ... other stuff
    include_package_data=True,
    name="esm_tools",
    packages=["configs", "esm_tools"],
    package_dir={"configs": "configs", "esm_tools": "esm_tools"},
    package_data={'configs': ['*']},
    version="4.1.5",
    zip_safe=False,
)
```

However, I can't access the package data with:

```
In [1]: import pkg_resources                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       

In [2]: pkg_resources.resource_listdir("esm_tools", "config")                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-f0f255c14df6> in <module>
----> 1 pkg_resources.resource_listdir("esm_tools", "config")

/global/AWIsoft/miniconda/4.7.12/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py in resource_listdir(self, package_or_requirement, resource_name)
   1161         """List the contents of the named resource directory"""
   1162         return get_provider(package_or_requirement).resource_listdir(
-> 1163             resource_name
   1164         )
   1165 

/global/AWIsoft/miniconda/4.7.12/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py in resource_listdir(self, resource_name)
   1439 
   1440     def resource_listdir(self, resource_name):
-> 1441         return self._listdir(self._fn(self.module_path, resource_name))
   1442 
   1443     def metadata_listdir(self, name):

/global/AWIsoft/miniconda/4.7.12/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py in _listdir(self, path)
   1608 
   1609     def _listdir(self, path):
-> 1610         return os.listdir(path)
   1611 
   1612     def get_resource_stream(self, manager, resource_name):

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/ollie/pgierz/dev/esm_tools/esm_tools/esm_tools/config'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: So after installation, `configs/machines` should be accessible under `esm_tools/config/machines`?

Comment: Can you show what's inside `pkg_resources/__init__.py`? From your traceback, it's evident that your path is wrong: `'/home/ollie/pgierz/dev/esm_tools/esm_tools/esm_tools/config'`. `esm_tools` 3 times in the path can't be right. So it would be helpful to see, what `get_provider` function does.

Comment: @DmitriiAltukhov [`get_provider` is part of `setuptools`](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/blob/2a55538aaf5cbcfeaf3e8b79866d3144fb8c324a/pkg_resources/__init__.py#L354-L364).

Comment: You probably only need to add an empty `__init__.py` file in `configs` directory. You probably also can delete the `package_dir` line, seems useless to me. It would be helpful to show the output of `python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel`

Comment: So, to clarify, I keep the project itself here: `/home/ollie/pgierz/dev/esm_tools/esm_tools`, that's the top level where I put the tree output above. The project, containing multiple repositories, is `esm_tools`, and the specific repo I'm working on, is (unfortunately) also named esm_tools. The contents of `__init__.py` are very small, just: `__version__, __author__ and __email__`

Comment: @pgierz if you want to remap `configs` to `esm_tools/config` in the installed package, this can be done, but AFAIK it won't work with editable installs. Otherwise, your current setup includes `configs` as a separate package (even if it's a namespace one), so `pkg_resources.resource_listdir('configs')` should work. You are calling `pkg_resources.resource_listdir("esm_tools", "config")` which is effectively "find directory `config` under `esm_tools`", which you won't get with the current setup.

Comment: @hoefling how would I do that? Do I understand that I can keep the configs directory separate, in the top level, in the actual repo, and when someone runs install, it will be moved to esm_tools/configs? That'd be ideal...

Comment: This is possible, but again, editable installs don't support that AFAIK, so you'll have to construct workarounds for local development. I will add an answer shortly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your call `pkg_resources.resource_listdir("esm_tools", "config")`, I assume you want to remap `configs` to `esm_tools.config` in the installed package:

```
site-packages
├── esm_tools
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── config
│   │   ├── machines
│   │   ├── scope
```

This means you have to do the following things:

1. Tell `setuptools` to include a subpackage `esm_tools.config` (even if it doesn't really exist in source code base and is technically a namespace one, we'll construct it via further configuration)
2. Tell `setuptools` where the sources for the new `esm_tools.config` package are located (this is again just a necessary measure to tell `setuptools` what to include in the dist. The package itself won't provide any Python sources since no Python files are located in `configs`).
3. Tell `setuptools` to include package data for `esm_tools.config` from the correct path.

Example:

```
setup(
    ...,
    packages=['esm_tools', 'esm_tools.config'],           # 1
    package_dir={'esm_tools.config': 'configs'},          # 2
    package_data={'esm_tools.config': ['../configs/*']},  # 3
)
```

Note that this won't work with editable installs (neither via `pip install --editable .` nor with `python setup.py develop`), so you will have to construct more or less ugly local workarounds with symlinks or `.pth` files or whatever. The wheel dist (built via `python setup.py bdist_wheel` or `pip wheel`) will work out of the box, for source dists you'll have to include the `configs` dir via `MANIFEST.in` as `package_data` won't be read at `sdist` time:

```
# MANIFEST.in
...
graft configs
```

Comment: Great answer! Wondering if `include_package_data=True` is still necessary (depends on whether or not there are other package data files not mentioned in the question).

Comment: @sinoroc thanks! Indeed, neither `include_package_data=True` nor `zip_safe=False` are relevant for the example code in the answer, I have just copied the code from the question and edited stuff out.

Comment: Important note for anyone else: be careful here with `config` vs `configs`. I had a typo and was briefly confused.

Comment: This is twice the same line. I don't see what you're pointing at.